# Cast an std::array to another data type at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, c++11, compile-time

Is there a way in C++11 to cast an array of one type to another data type at compile-time :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
   static constexpr std::array<double, 3> darray{{1.5, 2.5, 3.5}};
   static constexpr std::array<int, 3> iarray(darray); // not working
   // Is there a way to cast an array to another data type ? 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd write a function that explicitly casts the elements one-by-one

Comment: In C++11 you can't even read the array in a constexpr way. Assuming your implementation makes operator[] constexpr as an extension, you can create a constexpr function that creates your iarray.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Even with std::get ?

Comment: Check the standard, the array overloads of get don't have constexpr on them.

Comment: @Marc I think you can cheat and `reinterpret_cast<double const*>(&darray)[i]` but that doesn’t help you for writing, only for reading. Since assignment is never a constant expression there’s no way to assign the values, not even in a recursive `constexpr` function.

Comment: @MarcGlisse : and if I use a raw c-array, can I both construct and access the data at compile-time ?

Comment: reinterpret_cast is not constexpr. It is possible to construct constexpr arrays, just like darray.

Comment: If darray was a C array but iarray was still a std::array, you could do it. Making iarray a C array would give you trouble with assignment.

Comment: @Marc Ah damn. On construction: sure. But not element assignment, and that’s what we need here one way or another, don’t we (maybe one could go the detour via tuple concatenation to create it …).

Comment: See ecatmur's answer (no assignment). Except that he is cheating by using std::get, so he might as well use operator[] instead.

Comment: @Marc Hum, I forgot about parameter pack expansion. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a very simple solution with a single variadic function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Type, typename OtherType, std::size_t Size, typename... Types, class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Types) != Size>::type>
constexpr std::array<Type, Size> convert(const std::array<OtherType, Size> source, const Types... data);

template<typename Type, typename OtherType, std::size_t Size, typename... Types, class = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Types) == Size>::type, class = void>
constexpr std::array<Type, Size> convert(const std::array<OtherType, Size> source, const Types... data);

template<typename Type, typename OtherType, std::size_t Size, typename... Types, class>
constexpr std::array<Type, Size> convert(const std::array<OtherType, Size> source, const Types... data)
{
    return convert<Type>(source, data..., static_cast<const Type>(source[sizeof...(data)]));
}

template<typename Type, typename OtherType, std::size_t Size, typename... Types, class, class>
constexpr std::array<Type, Size> convert(const std::array<OtherType, Size> source, const Types... data)
{
    return std::array<Type, Size>{{data...}};
}

int main()
{
   static constexpr std::array<double, 3> darray{{1., 2., 3.}};
   static constexpr std::array<int, 3> iarray = convert<int>(darray);
   std::cout<<(std::integral_constant<int, iarray[2]>())<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 although as mentioned in ecatmur's answer `operator[]` has to be declared `constexpr` for this to work which is unfortunately missing in the current standard (although with gcc it is `constexpr`).

Answer (score 9):

No, but you can do it by hand fairly easily using the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices), assuming the implementation provides `constexpr` `std::get` (or equivalently a `constexpr` overload of `operator[]`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

// http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct indices {};
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices: build_indices<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...>: indices<Is...> {};

template<typename T, typename U, size_t i, size_t... Is>
constexpr auto array_cast_helper(
   const std::array<U, i> &a, indices<Is...>) -> std::array<T, i> {
   return {{static_cast<T>(std::get<Is>(a))...}};
}

template<typename T, typename U, size_t i>
constexpr auto array_cast(
   const std::array<U, i> &a) -> std::array<T, i> {
   // tag dispatch to helper with array indices
   return array_cast_helper<T>(a, build_indices<i>());
}

int main() {
   static constexpr std::array<double, 3> darray{{1.5, 2.5, 3.5}};
   static constexpr std::array<int, 3> iarray = array_cast<int>(darray);
}
```

If your implementation doesn't provide `constexpr` `get` or `operator[]`, you can't use `array` as there's no current standard way to access array elements `constexpr`; your best bet is to use your own implementation of `array` with the `constexpr` extensions.

The `constexpr` library additions are proposed for addition to the standard in [n3470](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3470.html).

Comment: A few empty lines (and putting function bodies on a separate line) between the definitions would increase readability thousandfold … furthermore, is `std::get` `constexpr` for `std::array`? Not according to cppreference.com.

Comment: @KonradRudolph cheers, fixed and discussed.  Feel free to edit for clarity.

Comment: You can use the templated conversion operator trick to remove the need to pass `int` to `array_cast`.

Comment: I'd rather replace the std::array with auto than remove the simple int ;-)

Comment: @balki: Failure of `constexpr` is silent IIRC.

Comment: No, failure to initialize a constexpr variable is not silent.

Comment: "you can do it by hand fairly easily" - +1 for taking the time to work through the problem for the OP but I don't think you can describe it as 'fairly easily'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an unmaintainable mess of cryptic template code that won't even currently compile with the most commonly used C++ compiler, and avoiding ungood redundancy in the number specs, simply use a macro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

#define MY_VALUES( T ) {T(1.5), T(2.5), T(3.5)}

int main()
{
    static constexpr std::array<double, 3>   darray  = { MY_VALUES( double ) };
    static constexpr std::array<int, 3>      iarray  = { MY_VALUES( int ) };
    // Whatever...
}
```

This is the kind of stuff macros are good at.

Just make sure to minimize the possibility of name collision by using an all uppercase macro name, and maybe some custom prefix.

---

General advice: don't be too clever, keep it simple.

Keep in mind, someone has to maintain it later.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast, but you can copy:

```
static constexpr std::array<double, 3> darray{{1.5, 2.5, 3.5}};
std::array<int, 3> iarray;

std::copy(begin(darray), end(darray), begin(iarray));
```

Unfortunately `iarray` cannot be `constexpr` any more in this case.

Comment: The question specifically requires the conversion be done at compile-time.

Comment: @Ben But since that’s not possible in the current C++ standard (see ecatmur’s answer & comments), this is the next best thing.