# Cast an array of strings to an array of char*

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get rid of the `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’` warning, my code looks like the following:

```cpp
char* var[] = {"abc", "def"};
// many more lines like this ...
```

One solution is to prepend each string literal with `(char*)` however that's ugly and unmaintainable. Ideally I'd like to be able to edit these lines to say

```cpp
char* var[] = array_cast<char*>({"abc", "def"});
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279821/cast-an-stdarray-to-another-data-type-at-compile-time) for almost the same problem except it deals with `std::array` instead of plain C arrays and array variables rather than initializer lists.

I want to avoid using `std::array`, `std::string`, `const char*`, `std::vector` since the functions that eventually get called accept non-const `char**`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? It is just a bad idea and code.

Comment: The correct solution is adding the required `const` to the declaration: `const char* var[] = { ... };`

Comment: ... and if you can't add `const` because you are going to modify the strings, any cast-based solution will be wrong anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need a non-const char array

Comment: Then you can't use literal strings, as the are *constant*. Perhaps `std::string var[] = { ... };` would be a better choice? And even better, use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @kryppon If you need a non-constant character array then declare a two-dimensional array initialized by string literals.

Comment: If you need `char*` because of your API, just `const_cast` it, but have in mind that you are still not allowed to modify them.

Comment: String literals are `const char[]` and even if you cast `const` away with some tricks, you still can't modify them. Compiler is allowed to do all sorts of optimizations based on the fact that `const` value will not be changed in runtime.

Comment: @pptaszni you're right, I'm trying to fit an API, I don't actually need to modify the strings myself. How can I use `const_cast` in a convenient way?

Comment: Don't, just don't cast away `const`. Instead use an array or a vector of `std::string` objects, and when you need a pointer to the string to allow for modifications, use `&var[i][0]`. But do remember that the pointer can only be used to modify the existing characters in the string, the API isn't allowed to use e.g. `strcat` or similar to attempt to resize the string. The API *can* shorten the string (by writing the null-terminator in the middle) but then you need to resize the `std::string` object to the correct length.

Comment: I appreciate the input telling me to do something else than the question asks like using a `vector` or `const` but that's not what I want to do. I have a brace-enclosed initializer list of string literals and I want to store them in a non-const char array without the compiler complaining - that's it. I want to know if that's possible and if so, how. It's quite simple.

Comment: What you want to do is simply not valid in C++. It might not even be valid in C (considering that literal strings might not be modified even through they are not explicitly constant as in C++). You say you need to pass a `char**` to some function, but *what* function? What is that function supposed to do with the strings?

Comment: As a possible workaround, how about two arrays: One proper C++ array with `std::string` objects; And a second `char*` array which contains pointers to the strings in the first array?

Comment: It's not wrong or invalid. otherwise I wouldn't get away with a mere warning. If it is XY problem, then answer the Y please. I want to map `(char*)` to array items, is it possible or not?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that could work. Could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: @krypton there are kind of error in code that give only warning (because standard requires "diagnostics") There are even errors that do not require diagnostics at all on compile  time and you may or maynot find out that you actually have an UB. Or non-portable code (across compilers or compiler versions).

Comment: @kryphon `then answer the Y please.` We cannot do that until you tell us what Y is. The nature of XY problem is that we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have arrived at a solution. It requires two arrays one of which needs to be cleaned up afterwards so it can surely be improved.

```cpp
template<size_t N, size_t... Is>
constexpr char** 
array_cast(const std::array<const char*, N>& arr, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
   return new char*[]{const_cast<char*>(std::get<Is>(arr))...};
}

template<size_t N>
constexpr char**
array_cast(const std::array<const char*, N>& arr)
{
   return array_cast(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

const std::array var {"abc", "def"};

char** result = array_cast(var);
```

Answer (score 2):

C string literals are constant and will be placed in the .data section and protected from being modified by the hardware. No amount of casting will fix that.

C++ strings (`std::string`) are mutable so use those:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

std::string var[] = {"abc"s, "def"s};
```

Although why you would want mutable strings in an array escapes me.

Answer (score 2):

`"abc"` and `"def"` are **string literals** of type `const char[4]` which **decays** to `const char*`(and not `char*`) due to **type decay**.

So you need to add a low-level `const` indicating that `var` is an array of *pointers to `const char`*(instead of *pointer to `char`*) as shown below:

```
const char* var[] = {"abc", "def"};
```

Or better yet use `std::array` or `std::vector` with elements of type `std::string`.

```
std::vector<std::string> var{"abc", "def"};
```

Answer (score 1):

As a possible workaround, it would be possible to use two arrays, one with `std::string` objects, and one with `char*` pointers to the strings in the first array:

```
std::array<std::string, 2> real_strings = {{ "foo", "bar" }};
char* wrap[] = { &real_strings[0][0], &real_strings[1][0] };
```

This can of course be used together with a vector and dynamic allocation and a loop to initialize the wrapper array, if the number of strings is not known at compile-time (or may change at run-time).

---

On a personal note, to me it all seems like a design flaw in the API you're using.

Comment: This is unfortunately even more verbose than `char* var[] = {(char*)"foo", (char*)"bar"}`. Can the `wrap` array be built with a function template of some sort? The number of strings *is* known at compile-time - they are given as an array of literals and not changed at any point.

Comment: @kryppon As a general rule: Whenever you feel the need to do C-style cast, then it's a sign you're doing something wrong. Yes this workaround is verbose, but at least it's *correct*. And just because the compiler only gives a "warning" doesn't make it less incorrect. Casting away warnings is in 99% of all cases the wrong way to solve them (and 100% wrong in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modifiable 2d array of chars like this:

```
char var[][4] = {"abc", "def"};
```

Comment: That would work if all strings were the same length which is not the case unfortunately (admittedly that is what the example in the OP shows so my apologies if I created that impression).